# SQL Server: UPDATE after pivot (unpivot needed?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, pivot, unpivot

Two days ago I asked how to use pivot in SQL to transpose a table.

With your help I got it right, here the solution: [SQL server: Transpose Rows to Columns (n:m relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483488/sql-server-transpose-rows-to-columns-nm-relationship)

I'm running SQL Server 2012, with an OBDC-connection, programming in C#.

So now I have:

```
| mitID | Name   | FamName | DOB        | abtIDref | HV            | PEV        | Drive      | Nex        |
|-------|--------|---------|------------|----------|---------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1     | Frank  | Sinatra | 12.12.1915 | 1        | **30.5.2016** |            | 05.06.2015 | 02.11.2015 |
| 2     | Robert | Downey  | 4.4.1965   | 2        | 27.7.2014     | 01.01.2016 | 20.01.2015 |            |
```

I get this with following SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Descr)
FROM Faehigkeiten ORDER BY faeID

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT mitID, Name, FamName, DOB, abtIDref, ' + @cols + '
    FROM(
       SELECT mitID, Name, FamName, DOB, abtIDref, [when], descr
       FROM Mitarbeiter m
       JOIN[Link - List] l ON m.mitID = l.mitIDref
       JOIN Faehigkeiten f ON f.faeID = l.feaIDref
    ) a
    PIVOT(MAX([when]) FOR descr IN(' + @cols + ')) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But when I enter a new date (shown in asterisk above), or change a name of a member, how do I save the data?

I thought about `unpivot`, but I have no idea how to use it in my case.

My solution would be to loop through all the rows and compare it to existing entries ... but that could take a long time with lots of members.

Can you point me in some direction, wether it is possible to `UPDATE` this an easy way? I only need `UPDATE` no `INSERT` since new rows are forbidden.

Right now I have no class for my members. I load my `DataGridView` in C# with the following code:

```
BindingSource bsMember = new BindingSource();
bsMember.DataSource = DBMember.Get();
dgv.DataSource = bsMember;
```

The `DBMember.Get()` returns a `DataTable` made with the above shown SQL code.

Sorry, I have no approach except my loop through each row :/

EDIT: The provided duplicate is hard for me to follow because of the `JOIN` in my SQL-code. Can i JOIN while updating?
Please consider helping me directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updates on PIVOTs in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726582/updates-on-pivots-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Maybe i can solve it with this, i'll give it a try, but since i'm new to all this dynamic SQL and pivot i don't count much on myself :D